# Connect remotely to an Android device via adb

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, adb, android-wifi

I'm just testing the `adb` and I'm wondering if this is possible.

I mean, let's say I have adb installed on a `aws` instance, whatever the Ip it may be.

Then from there, I want to connect to my Android device via `adb` I don't know if `adb connect` can do the trick having the external Ip of the device.

From what I've learned, seems like it is possible, but it's kind of confusing.

Also, I see it's possible to connect without having the device rooted.

But most tutorials or examples are based on wifi, I just want to know if there is a workaround or even a command which can make this possible remotely.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would try looking into [Vysor](http://www.vysor.io/). The main purpose of this tool is to be able to control an Android device remotely, but it also provides an option to share the adb connection to the device without a root. Its a powerful tool, that as many applications.